# Set up Drupal to use alternative nodes for different incoming urls?

Tags: commerce

I have a Drupal website set up selling a single product. Currently the transactions are being processed with paypal with simple buttons set up on a specified node (e.g. *www.website.com/buy*).

I want to start a referral or affiliate system so that drupal will notice the different incoming links (*www.website.com/referral*) and will then always route (*www.website.com/buy*) to (*www.website.com/buy_referral*) once it detects the different incoming links. This is because I will set up different PayPal buttons for different referrals on different buy_referral nodes.

Is there a module available to do so? or is there an easier way to do things?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you want to track the referral only during the web session or do you want to be able to also track it for a number of days after the initial visits? Some affiliate programs have a 30 day "cookie duration" meaning they give credit for 30 days after the initial visit.

Comment: only during that session. if someone bought the product coming from the referral link, they would get credit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `mod_rewrite` features in your site's `.htaccess` to redirect before Drupal even gets started. This would increase performance vs. using JavaScript.

Implementation details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151385/redirect-on-the-basis-of-referer-http-referer-htaccess

More about Drupal's `.htaccess`:

http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Contents of Drupal's `.htaccess`:

http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/HEAD:/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using jQuery/javascript if all you have to do is change the href of a link.  For example, let's say you have:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/buy">Buy Me</a>
```

You could change that (and any others) to:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/buy_referral">Buy Me</a>
```

with the following jQuery:

```
$("a[href=http://www.website.com/buy]").each(function(){
  this.href="http://www.website.com/buy_referral";
```

Of course, you have to figure out when to do that, but I'd do that based upon a class in the body of the node coming in:

```
if $('body').hasClass('referral') {
  $("a[href=http://www.website.com/buy]").each(function(){
    this.href="http://www.website.com/buy_referral";
}
```

but you could also scan through the DOM for hrefs with referral in them if you have no control over the node content itself.

Anyways, it's late here and I am just freethinking so this may or may not be a good idea, or even totally accurate js but hope it helps out or gives you some ideas...